# How to do asynchronous validation with Reactive Forms (Angular2 RC3)?

Tags: javascript, validation, asynchronous, angular

I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-form-validation-9b26f73fcb81#.tdbirqat1) to do asynchronous validations. This doesn't work with RC3 (Reactive Froms) anymore.

How to do asynchronous validation here?

```
this.username = new FormControl( '', [ <any>Validators.required, <any>ProfileValidator.usernameTaken ]);

...

class ProfileValidator {

 static usernameTaken(control: FormControl): Promise<{[key:string]:boolean}> {

   let q = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       resolve(null);
     }, 1000)
   });

   return q;
 }

}
```

**The FormControl is always invalid...**

Comment: Check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1068

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the form control should have async validators as the 3rd arg like so:

```
new FormControl( '', 
    [ <any>Validators.required], //sync
    [<any>ProfileValidator.usernameTaken ] //async
    );
```